# Taking photo using Android SurfaceView not refreshing using ICS and above

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I have created an app which takes photos and adds to a gallery, using the code from the Android dev site. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

It takes one photo and then should reload the camera preview so that you can take further photos which are added to a gallery. It's been working fine on Android v3.

On Android v4 the same software freezes the camera after the first photo so that a second can't be taken.

Has anything changed across the versions that may be causing this?

It's on the ACER A510 tablet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved - I had to do another call to startPreview() in the onPictureTaken method in my PictureCallback. I'm not sure yet what affect that will have on the older versions.

Comment: Awesome!  That is exactly what I was missing too!  Thank you!